# JavaScript regex \G + offset equivalent

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is there an equivalent of `\G` in JavaScript regular expressions? I need to match a pattern at an exact offset. Setting the `g` flag and `.lastIndex` searches forward from the given index, but won't match at the offset exactly.

[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/flags/) has this `y` modifier which might be what I'm looking for, but it doesn't appear to work in Node/V8.

Comment: Since there is no equivalent of the \G feature in javascript regexes, you should expose us the specific (or general) case(s) you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some hackery:

```
var XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp;

function makeOffsetPatt(patt, flags) {
    if(_.isUndefined(flags)) flags = 'gnsm';
    return XRegExp('(?:'+patt+')|(?<__NO_MATCH>)', flags);
}

XRegExp.prototype.match = function(str, offset) {
    var result = XRegExp.exec(str, this, offset);
    if(result === null || !_.isUndefined(result.__NO_MATCH)) return null;
    delete result.__NO_MATCH;
    return result;

};

var word = makeOffsetPatt('\\w+');
console.log(word.match('html { head {'));
console.log(word.match('html { head {',4));
console.log(word.match('html { head {',7));
```

Outputs:

```
[ 'html', index: 0, input: 'html { head {' ]
null
[ 'head', index: 7, input: 'html { head {' ]
```

If your pattern isn't found, it will try to match an empty string instead, which should always succeed. I then check for the existence of this empty match to determine if your pattern failed, clean up the match object and return it.

Comment: Are you sure that works if there's non-matching stuff between "lastIndex" and the start of a good match?

Comment: It seems that what you are looking for is more a "begining anchor" at a defined offset than the `\G` feature.

Comment: @Pointy: It seems to. In this case it will try to match a word character first, if that fails it tries matching the alternation (empty string) before advancing the cursor. This way it will always bail out before searching forward. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's exactly what `\G` is, isn't it? Neither `^` nor `\A` would work in this scenario.

Comment: Ah well if you're going to cheat and use xregexp then maybe this is fine :)

Comment: @Pointy I don't think the code above actually has any dependency on `XRegExp`. I haven't used any of its features yet. Although I'm going to update it in a sec with a more robust solution that depends on it...

Comment: `\G` match the start of the string (not the line) or the position after the last match. But once the match fails, there is no way to get other results (without an other entry point from an other path).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte In PCRE, `\G` matches at the given offset *exactly*.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* the only thing you can do is set `.lastIndex` to your starting point, try a match with `.exec()`, and then if you get a match check the updated value of `.lastIndex`. If it's equal to your starting position plus the length of the match result, then the match began exactly where you wanted.

So:

```
var re = /banana/g;
re.lastIndex = 6;

var mr = re.exec("hello banana");
if (mr[0].length + 6 === re.lastIndex)
  alert("good banana");
```

I would never claim that this is a "good" way of doing things, it's just the only possibility I know of.